# Is it possible to bind resource file X to publish profile Y?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Let's say I've got an ASP.NET MVC web app with 2 language files (french and german).
For this project, I've got 2 publish profiles (one to xxx.fr and the other to xxx.de).

Is it possible to tell the publish profiles which language file to deploy ?
And if it's possible, how ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create Web.config transforms based on the publish profile. For example, if you have a profile named `Foo.pubxml`, you can create a transform named `Web.Foo.config`.

You can set the culture and UI culture in Web.config like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization culture="nl" uiCulture="nl"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

So a transform would look like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.web>
        <globalization culture="fr" uiCulture="fr" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

By setting the culture, the correct resource files will automatically be used, assuming you follow the naming conventions like `Foo.resx` as the default (unspecified culture) and `Foo.fr.resx` for the `fr` culture.